# How can I copy a file from Dropbox/Drive/Onedrive to a specific path using getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor() from Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, storage-access-framework

I'm trying to copy a file from a generic hosting file service as Dropbox/Drive/Onedrive to a specific path in my device.

I created a working example to copy a jpg file, but what I would like to create is a version for copying these types: .docx, .pdf, .pptx, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .mp3, .mp4, .xlsx.

What do I have to do? How can I modify my code?

Thanks

```
// the flow start from here
public void newFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file"), NEW_FILE_PRIVATE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == NEW_FILE_PRIVATE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri currentUri = null;
            currentUri = data.getData();

            String contentString = currentUri.toString();

            if (contentString.contains("com.dropbox.android") ||
                contentString.contains("com.microsoft.skydrive") ||
                contentString.contains("com.google.android.apps.docs.storage")) {
                try {
                    copyFileContent(currentUri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("cloud error", "error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private String copyFileContent(Uri uri) throws IOException {

    ParcelFileDescriptor pFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = pFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);

    pFileDescriptor.close();

    /* temporary path */
    String extension = getMimeType(getApplicationContext(), uri);

    String temporaryFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            .concat("/").concat("temporaryfile")
            .concat(".").concat(extension);

    File file = new File(temporaryFilePath);

    OutputStream outStream = null;

    try {
        /* make a new bitmap from your file */

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return temporaryFilePath;
}
```

Edit
Thanks to @CommonsWare I wrote a solution for getting the file extension using this code:

```
public String getExtension(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String extension;

    if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
        final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        extension = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(context.getContentResolver().getType(uri));
    } else {
        extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.getPath())).toString());
    }

    return extension;
}
```

Edit 2
With the help of @Greenapps I implemented this solution:

```
private String copyFileContent(Uri uri) throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

    /* temporary path */
    String extension = getMimeType(getApplicationContext(), uri);
    String temporaryFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
        .concat("/").concat("temporaryfile")
        .concat(".").concat(extension);

    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(temporaryFilePath);

    final byte[] b = new byte[8192];
    for (int r;(r = inputStream.read(b)) != -1;) outStream.write(b, 0, r);

    return temporaryFilePath;
}
```

Does exists a method for getting the filename instead of naming it "temporary file"?

Edit 3

```
private String copyFileContent(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

    String uriString = uri.toString();
    String fileName = "";
    if (!uriString.contains("com.dropbox.android")) {
        Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        fileName = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
    } else {
        fileName = uriString.substring(uriString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, uriString.lastIndexOf("."));
    }

    /* temporary path */
    String extension = getMimeType(getApplicationContext(), uri);
    String temporaryFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
        .concat("/").concat(egoName)
        .concat("/").concat("PRIVATE")
        .concat("/").concat(fileName)
        .concat(".").concat(extension);

    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(temporaryFilePath);

    final byte[] b = new byte[8192];
    for (int r;
        (r = inputStream.read(b)) != -1;) outStream.write(b, 0, r);

    return temporaryFilePath;
}
```

Comment: `code works if my file is a jpg`. What are you trying to accomplish? You read a jpg file, convert it to a bitmap and save it as a png file? For what? What do you want to do with other files? Converting doc to html? Very unclear what you want.

Comment: Hi @greenapps as I wrote "what I'm trying to do is to find a solution for every type of file". I created a working code to get a jpg and now I would like to modify it for getting a generic file. What can I do for making the question clearer? thanks

Comment: Very unclear. No answer at all. What kind of solution are you after? Whqat is your aim? You read a file. Ok. And then? What to do with the content? Why are you reading to begin with? What do you want to do with a generic file?

Comment: @greenapps 

Step 1: obtain a file from dropbox/drive/onedrive.

Step 2: save the file in my device in a specific path.

Problem: if I set the intent type I know exactly what I'm searching for and I can handle the file with no problems. I wrote a working example for a jpg file. How can I do the same thing for every type of file?

Now is clear?

Comment: No. Because if you want to copy a jpg file from dropbox to your device then i do not understandf that you first make a bitmap out of it and then save the bitmap as a png. Why not just copy the jpg directly? Well if that is what you want: copying files from dropbox to your device. Is that your aim? If so then why didn't you tell that you want to copy files? If it is something else you want then please tell what you want as i have still no idea else where you are after. What should happen with a doc file for instance? Or a xml file?

Comment: @greenapps I edited the question. Is now clear?

Comment: So you want to copy files. Well then it is really time to tell why you convert a jpg to bitmap and then save the bitmap as png when you want to copy a jpg. This is the third time i ask!

Comment: `created a working example to copy a jpg file,`. Well that is not exactly code which copies a file. Very confusing what you do and suggest.

Comment: @greeapps I convert a jpg to bitmap, because I don't know how to save directly the jpg in a path. Do you have a better method? When you talk about png is where I use the compress method?

Comment: A better method? Please dont call what you do a method to copy a file. I wonder why you did not google for copy file as copying files is a pretty basic thing to do. You would then have seen that you would read in a loop chuncks from a (File)InputStream and directly write them to a (File)OutputStream. You have already those two streams. Do away with the rest. If it can copy a jpg it can copy all files. The type of file is of course irrelevant if you have a normal copy function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130473/discussion-between-machoprogrammer-and-greenapps).

Comment: @greenapps where is my InputStream? I have an URI not an InputStream and that's why I wrote that code. Could you please tell me how can I get the InputStream from the URI? With the InputStream all would be very easy.

Comment: Sorry, i oversaw that. `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`.

Comment: @greenapps `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` is exactly what I'm searching for! Thanks I try right now.

Comment: @greenapps I changed the code and you can read it in my second edit. I have another question for solving the problem does exists a method for getting the filename instead of naming it "temporary file"?

Comment: Please show the values of `data.getData().getPath()` and `data.getData().toString()` if the user chooses a dropbox file.

Comment: @greenapps path: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u567830796/scratch/images/example.jpg`
toString:  `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u567830796/scratch/images/example.jpg`
I found a solution that seems to be good, what do you think?

Comment: I found this part of solution `if (!uriString.contains("com.dropbox.android")) Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME); returnCursor.moveToFirst(); fileName = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);` for all the rest of the code you helped me a lot and if you answer at the question I can UP vote you. Thanks again

Comment: Ok. A last remark. `private String readFileContent(Uri uri)`. The method name is wrong. Change to `private boolean copyFileContent(Uri uri, String destinationdir)`.

Comment: @greeapps thanks again! Today I learned a lot because of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about a day it was clear that you just want to copy files.

Do it in the normal way by opening an `InputStream`.

```
 InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Then read chuncks from the stream and write them to a `FileOutputStream`.

As DropBox is full of files the filename (with extension) can be found in `data.getData().getPath()`. But using the display name column is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get file name and extension from Storage Access Framework using getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor()?

There is no filename or extension. You are working with content, not files. You can get a "display name" (e.g., `DocumentFile` and `getName()`), but this does not have to be a filename or contain any sort of file extension.

> This code works if my file is a jpg, but what I'm trying to do is to find a solution for every type of file without using the intent.setType("image/*") or generalizing it

Get the MIME type of the content via `DocumentFile` and `getType()`. Use `MimeTypeMap` to help you convert that to a candidate file extension.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I'll try it!